# How to pass a PHP constant as service argument in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, constants, yaml

When defining services using the configuration file, how can I pass a PHP constant (`CURLAUTH_DIGEST` in this example) as a constructor argument?

I **can't test it right now** but I assume that:

```yaml
services:
    my_service:
        class: "%my_service.class%"
        arguments: [CURLAUTH_DIGEST]
```

Wouldn't work because `CURLAUTH_DIGEST` is converted to a `string`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a way to do this

1. Add a line in your config to include a `.php` configuration

   <kbd>**app/config/config.yml**</kbd>

   ```
   imports:
       - { resource: constants.php }
   ```
2. Create a new file `constants.php`

   <kbd>**app/config/constants.php**</kbd>

   ```
   <?php

   $container->setParameter('curlauth.digest', CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
   ```
3. You can now access this constant in your service

   <kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml**</kbd>

   ```
   services:
       my_service:
           class: "%my_service.class%"
           arguments: [%curlauth.digest%]
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this shows us how to do it in YAML. The duplicate answer (I didn't read very well) states that it's not possible to do it (only in XML). I voted to close, now I'll do for reopen.