# Symfony2 cache and parameters

Tags: php, symfony, caching, parameters

I have an odd app set up, multiple sub domains all pointing to the same Symfony2 install.

The subdomain simply changes a single parameter within the application so that different content is loaded.

This parameter is being cached however, so visiting a.site.com and then b.site.com makes A's content appear rather than B's.

Is there another approach I can use?

Is there a way I can add this parameter the cache's hash or something similar so that when the parameter changes within the app the content can change.

I am using this method to pass the constant from the sub domain into the Symfony2 application

[How to pass a PHP constant as service argument in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878021/how-to-pass-a-php-constant-as-service-argument-in-symfony-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a service to parse the host name, that service was then available within my Controllers.

```
class GameSystem {

    public function getGameSystemName()
    {
        $ar = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $first = reset($ar);

        $game_system_short_name = strtolower($first);

        return $game_system_short_name;
    }
}
```

Initially I had tried to use the constant value set in each subdomain's index file. But this was failing and having some really odd effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symfony's Request Object to get the URL and parse that for the subdomain. Use that to create your configuration parameter because it won't be cached.

Like this:

```
echo $request->getUri();
```

Symfony's API can be a great resource, but a bit hard to read. http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html